# bash search output for similar text and perform calculation between the 2

Tags: bash, shell

I am working on a script that will run a pm2 list and assign it to a variable, wait X seconds and run it again assigning it to a different variable. Then I run those through a `comm <(echo "$pm2_1") <(echo "$pm2_2") -3` that gives me only the output that is different between the 2 in a nice format

```
name      ID restart count
prog-name 0  1
prog-name 0  2
prog-name-live 10 1
prog-name-live 10 8
prog-name-live 3 1
prog-name-live 3 4
prog-name-live 6 1
prog-name-live 6 6
```

What I need is a way to compare the restart counts on the 2 lines with similar IDs.. EX

```
name      ID restart count
prog-name 0  1
prog-name 0  2

prog-name-worker 10 1
prog-name-worker 10 8
```

Any ideas would be very helpful! 
Thanks

Comment: Seems like it should be a simple `awk` script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- awk supports hash hope that helps

  awk '{k=$1" "$2; a[k]=$3; print k, a[k]}'
- here is example of using it to find difference, you can try any logic

  awk '{k=$1" "$2; if (a[k]==0)a[k]=$3; else {a[k]-=$3; q=a[k]>0?a[k]:a[k]*-1;print k,q}}'

Comment: Worked Like a charm! Thank you so much for your help!